# Java method does not override

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

I am trying to display image fetch from database in a table view. Here is how I set up my table view with image column:

```
TableColumn prodImageCol = new TableColumn("IMAGES");
    prodImageCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Product, Image>("prodImage"));
    prodImageCol.setMinWidth(100);
    // setting cell factory for product image        
    prodImageCol.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<Product, Image>, TableCell<Product, Image>>() {
        @Override
        public TableCell<Product, Image> call(TableColumn<Product, Image> param) {
            TableCell<Product, Image> cell = new TableCell<Product, Image>() {
                @Override //Error here
                public void updateItem(Product item, boolean empty) {
                    if (item != null) {
                        ImageView imageview = new ImageView();
                        imageview.setFitHeight(50);
                        imageview.setFitWidth(50);
                        imageview.setImage((Image) item.getprodImage());
                        setGraphic(imageview);
                    }
                }
            };
            return cell;
        }
    });
```

However, I am getting method does not override or implement a method from a supertype. I have no idea why is it so because I follow the same thing from a website on how to display image in table view. Can somebody please explain to me why is it so? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I copy/past your code on my IDE and everything is fine I see no problems here .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**:  The signature of the updateItem method is:

```
@Override
protected void updateItem(Image image, boolean b) {
    super.updateItem(image, b);
}
```

I posted my original answer too quickly (before I got the same compile error you did).

You can have a method like this if you like:

```
public void updateItem(Product item, boolean empty);
```

You just can't annotate it with:

```
    @Override
```

Which means you are redefining a method with the exact same signature (name and arguments) from the base class.

Alternatively, reverse the generic type arguments:

```
<Image, Product> vs. <Product, Image>
```

Comment: I checked already but there's no difference. Am I missing some semi column somewhere? Somemore my images are not appearing. If I removed the override portion the column is showing writeableImage addresses. However, after I added the override there shows nothing

Comment: But I can't change the Product item to Image image, because I am getting something from the Product class

Comment: Then remove "@Override"

Comment: Incidentally the original code also compiles if you reverse the order of all generic parameters: <Image, Product> vs. <Product, Image>  Not sure if that is what you want, but that allows you to keep the original method signature, and keep the "@Override".   In short, the type of the first argument to updateItem() corresponds to the second generic type argument.